# Organize a List of Words Separated by Comma from Unorganized List of Words (TIPS ONLY IF POSSIBLE)

Tags: python

Basically, I have this long list of words (provided below) that I want to organize using Python. The problem is that the list of words don't already have commas + they are separated by line breaks and there are like 200 of them. Backspacing twice and adding a comma to each word seems a bit tedious and I'm sure there's some way to automate this in Python. However, I'm a beginner and can't really think of a method.

If possible, I'm looking for someone to point me in the right direction to solving this, because I really want to figure it out myself (for the most part, lol).

I want it to look like so:

```
[Adventurous, Aggressive, Agreeable, Alert, Alive, Amused]
```

(and so on)

---

This is how the list of words comes out when I copy/paste it:

```
adorable

adventurous

aggressive

agreeable

alert

alive

amused

angry

annoyed

annoying

anxious

arrogant

ashamed

attractive

average

awful

bad

beautiful

better

bewildered

black

bloody

blue

blue-eyed

blushing

bored

brainy

brave

breakable

bright

busy

calm

careful

cautious

charming

cheerful

clean

clear

clever

cloudy

clumsy

colorful

combative

comfortable

concerned

condemned

confused

cooperative

courageous

crazy

creepy

crowded

cruel

curious

cute

dangerous

dark

dead

defeated

defiant

delightful

depressed

determined

different

difficult

disgusted

distinct

disturbed

dizzy

doubtful

drab

dull
```

Comment: If you use pycharm/Notepad++, you can just select the text vertically and add the comma

Comment: Are you sure that desired output is correct? Why are all the words capitalized, and why aren't they in quotes? You can [edit] if needed. BTW, welcome to Stack Overflow! Check out the [tour], and [ask] if you want tips.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `tkinter` module to get the copied text from clipboard, then `split` the text on new line character `\n` finally `filter` any item that is just an empty string.

```py
import tkinter as tk
root = tk.Tk()
text = root.clipboard_get()
list(filter(lambda x: x != '', text.split('\n')))
```

**OUTPUT:**

```py
['adventurous', 'aggressive', 'agreeable', 'alert', 'alive', 'amused', 'angry', 'annoyed', 'annoying', 'anxious', 'arrogant', 'ashamed', 'attractive', 'average', 'awful', 'bad', 'beautiful', 'better', 'bewildered', 'black', 'bloody', 'blue', 'blue-eyed', 'blushing', 'bored', 'brainy', 'brave', 'breakable', 'bright', 'busy', 'calm', 'careful', 'cautious', 'charming', 'cheerful', 'clean', 'clear', 'clever', 'cloudy', 'clumsy', 'colorful', 'combative', 'comfortable', 'concerned', 'condemned', 'confused', 'cooperative', 'courageous', 'crazy', 'creepy', 'crowded', 'cruel', 'curious', 'cute', 'dangerous', 'dark', 'dead', 'defeated', 'defiant', 'delightful', 'depressed', 'determined', 'different', 'difficult', 'disgusted', 'distinct', 'disturbed', 'dizzy', 'doubtful', 'drab', 'dull']
```

Comment: Ew, don't use `list(filter(lambda))`, use a list comprehension instead: `[x for x in text.split('\n') if x]`. You don't even need to compare to the empty string cause it's falsy. So actually, you could do `list(filter(None, text.split('\n')))`, and that'd be better.